# StringTokenizer in java. Why is it adding one more space

Tags: java

I am using jdk 1.6 (it is older but ok). I have a function like this:

```
public static ArrayList gettokens(String input, String delim)
  {
    ArrayList tokenArray = new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(input, delim);
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens())
    {
      tokenArray.add(tokens.nextToken());
    }
    return tokenArray;
  }
```

My initial intention is to use tokens to clear the input string of duplicate emails (that is initial).

Let's say I have

```
input = ", email-1@email.com, email-2@email.com, email-3@email.com"; //yes with , at the beginning
delim = ";,";
```

And when I run above function the result is:

```
[email-1@email.com,  email-2@email.com,  email-3@email.com]
```

Which is fine, but there is added one more `space` between `,` and `email` .

Why is that? and how to fix it?

**Edit:**

here is the function that prints the output:

```
List<String> tokens = StringUtility.gettokens(email, ";,");
Set<String> emailSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(tokens);

emails = StringUtils.join(emailSet, ", ");
```

hehe, and now I see the answer.

**Edit 2 - the root cause:**

the root cause of the problem was that line of the code:

```
emails = StringUtils.join(emailSet, ", ");
```

Was adding an extra `", "` when joining tokens.
From the example above, one token would look like this `" email-1@email.com"` and when `join` in applied it will add `comma` and `space` before token. So *if a token has a space at the beginning of the string, then it will have two spaces between comma and space*.

Example:

`", "` + `" email-1@email.com"` = `",<space><space>email-1@email.com"`

Comment: Can you share the function that prints the output?

Comment: ok, I have updated, let me just test all the suggested answers

Comment: I don't think ', ' is valid in Java... maybe you meant ", " ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. I have used resource code in my code, but I didn't want to make it more complicated. I will update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing array list, it prints all the object comma and space separated. Your input also have a space before each comma so that causes two.

You can use:

```
tokenArray.add(tokens.nextToken().trim());
```

to remove unwanted spaces from your input.

Comment: +1 one for the suggested solution. I will mark other answer as it pointed me to the very cause of the problem so I could look for ways to fix it, but this for sure is the good approach. Thanks.

Comment: I have marked your answer as that is the one I was looking for. Other answer I wanted to mark used my personal edits to update his answer as his own edits. So in this case - personality wins :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better approach to use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method of String, just because it would be shorter. All you would need to do is :

```
     String[] values = input.split(delim);
```

It will return an array instead of a List.

The reason of your space is because you are adding it in your printing method.

```
List<String> tokens = StringUtility.gettokens(email, ";,");
Set<String> emailSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(tokens);

emails = StringUtils.join(emailSet, ", ");  //adds a space after a comma
```

So `StringTokenizer` works as expected.

In your case, without much modifying the code, you could use trim function to clear the spaces before removing duplicates, and then join with separator ", " like this:

```
 tokenArray.add(tokens.nextToken().trim());
```

And you will get result without two spaces.

Comment: You `reused` my edit and `posted as your own`. `Shame on you`. I would put -1 but I have already gave +1 for the answer. Shame on me.

Comment: ..which you made as `your-own`. All after `In your case,` were my edited comments. I am not interested in putting my name in the answer, but I don't like to someone make something as his own work if it is not. Ok, that is all from me.

Comment: A reviewer had already rejected your changes and since I agreed with the changes and it was a suggested edit in my answer. I put them there. Sorry if it upset you.

Comment: When you say a reviewer, you mean that somebody other rejected the review, and not you? hmm, is that possible? I am a bit new to stack.. I taught you are the one who can decline or reject the edits and no one other can reject?

Comment: Anyone with the right reputation (2000) can review an edit. doesn't matter if its my answer or not, SO is managed by the users.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the delim to include the sapce `", "` then it would not be conatined in the tokens elements.

Easier would be to use the [split() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) which returns a string array, so basically the method will look like:

```
public static ArrayList gettokens(String input, string delim)
{
   return Arrays.asList(input.split(delim));   
}
```

Comment: ok, what if I would have emails that are splitted with `;` and `,` I don't think this will work? but the suggestions looks very pretty and light as cake. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Aleks So you can use split(";, ")

Comment: thanks I will take a look at your approach. Even though this is small part of the code, I am working on much bigger systems where I have to investigate what solution will not affect other solutions. So I will give it a try and test it a little later. +1 for nice clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've got spaces in your string, and `ArrayList`'s implementation of `toString` adds a space before each element. The idea is that you've got a list of `"x"`, `"y"` and `"z"`, the output should be `"[x, y, z]"` rather than `"[x,y,z]"`

Your real problem probably is that you've kept the spaces in the tokens. Fix:

```
public static List<String> gettokens(String input, String delim)
  {
    ArrayList<String> tokenArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(input, delim);
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens())
    {
      tokenArray.add(tokens.nextToken().trim());
    }
    return tokenArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no space or comma in between.

Try to print your ArrayList as:

```
for(Object obj: tokenArray )
    System.out.println(obj);
```